# Реализация фильтра по городам: лоигка и порядок действий

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Добрый день! Я только закончил изучение PHP и MySQL и сейчас тренируюсь с созданием первого сайта. Можете объяснить порядок создания фильтра по городам? Есть пользовательские посты, в которых они указывают город, как параметр. Другие пользователи должны иметь возможность отфильтровать все посты на сайте по какому-либо из городов. 
Я вот не очень понимаю логику создания такого фильтра. Нужно ли создать две БД (одну с инфо постов, другую по городам), потом к выпадающему списку "прикрутить" id по городам обеих таблиц? Или как это делается? 
Код не пишите, хочу сам сделать, просто подскажите логику и очередность. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В БД должна быть таблица городов. В таблице постов должна быть ссылка на эту таблицу. При фильтрации выполняете запрос

```
SELECT * FROM posts pst WHERE pst.city_id = <требуемый id города>
```